# Gradle - use folder name within task

Tags: gradle

In my JSF project I'm using https://github.com/obecker/gradle-lesscss-plugin to compile LESS files to CSS. The CSS files are placed in `src/main/webapp/resources/default/1_0/css` folder. After updating CSS files the version number `1_0` needs to be increased. So is it possible to make the script below look for folder with the highest number inside `src/main/webapp/resources/default`, and use it in the `dest` variable instead of hard coding the version number?

```
lesscss {
    source = fileTree("src/main/scripts/less") {
        include "foo.less"
    }
    dest = "src/main/webapp/resources/default/1_0/css"
    compress = true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given, that you only need to find the greatest number, some plain old groovy can help here: just sort the directory names, and take the last one.

```
def resources = file("src/main/webapp/resources/default")

//choosing the latest happens here
def latest = resources.list().sort().last()

//take the 'css' dir relative to the project root
dest = file(new File(latest, 'css')).toString()
```

Using gradle's `file` method, you make sure the file path is relative to the project root.